# Getting the route from a Symfony request and passing it to an included twig file?

Tags: php, symfony, routes, twig, session-variables

I wish to access the $route variable generated in my controller from an included file in my twig templates and after many attempts I am failing to do so.

I define the $route variable at the controller like this:

```
$route = $request->attributes->get('_route');
```

Then I send the variables to my twig template

```
return $this->render('destinations/index.html.twig', [
            'route' => $route,
            'locale' => $locale,
            'langs' => $langs,
            'menu' => $menu
        ]);
```

From base.html.twig I call navbar.html.twig

```
{{ include('shared/navbar.html.twig') }}
```

When I try to print {{ route }} from inside navbar.html.twig I get a symfony error saying that route variable does not exist.

Also, if I try {{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') }} from base.html.twig I get the route, but if I do so from shared/navbar.html.twig I get "null". Why is that happening?

Comment: Is the include inside a macro by chance?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by macro? I include them from base.html.twig

Comment: See [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/macro.html), because that could have been the issue

Comment: Variables passed to a template will not be available to parent templates.  Which explains why neither base.html.twig nor your navbar.html.twig has access to route.  However, every template has access to app.request so app.request.attributes.get('_route') should work fine in navbar.html.twig.  I just made a quick test and confirmed it.  You probably made a syntax error when you tried it.  So try again and keep it simple.  Assuming you are not using an embedded controller, which you probably should be, then it should work.

Comment: @Cerad OP is passing templates from the parent towards the included template anyway or am i misreading here? He has `index` which extends from `base` and in `base` OP has the include

Comment: @DarkBee no I was not using macros, but thanks. The inheritance pattern is the following Controller->index(extends base)->base->navbar.html.twig, When I run {{ dump(route) }} in base.html.twig I see the route name, when I copypaste that dump order in navbar.html.twig I get "Variable "route" does not exist" error.

Comment: Can you post the base template as well?

Comment: @DarkBee As I understand it, base.html.twig is including navbar.html.twig.  However, the exact structure is irrelevant.  All templates have access to global twig variables such as app.request.

Comment: @cerad, it must had been a syntax error since that part now is working but yet I am still blocked, now due to the langs variable. both index.html.twig base.html.twig can print it but when we get to the included navbar.html.twig file, it fails, and the twig solution of using the with parameter inside the include tag, did not work, neither.

Comment: @DarkBee `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{app.request.locale}}">
   .....
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block header %}
        
        {% include 'shared/navbar.html.twig' with { langs:langs } %}
            
        {% endblock %}
        {% block body %}
        
        {% endblock %}
        
        {% block footer %}
            {{ include('shared/footer.html.twig') }}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}
....
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>

Comment: Well can't reproduce, check the context with `{{ dump(_context|keys) }}`

Comment: @user2833987 You can save yourself a great deal of trouble by using an [embedded controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#embedding-controllers) for your nav bar stuff.  Basically you get your own dedicated controller action in which you can inject whatever you want directly into your navbar twig file.

Answer (score 0):

If your controller from `shared/navbar.html.twig` is called from a `render(controller())` try sometink like this :

```php
public function yourAction(Request $request)
{
    $mainRequest = $this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest();
    $route = $mainRequest->get('_route');
    
    // stufff
    return $this->render('destinations/index.html.twig', [
        'route' => $route,
        'locale' => $locale,
        'langs' => $langs,
        'menu' => $menu
    ]);

}
```

and dump `route`.

Comment: The issue is that I could dump route in both index.html.twig and base.html.twig files but dumping route in navbar.html.twig file would give an error.

Comment: If the navbar block is called with a `render_esi` or `render(controller())`, it can be explained because of the object Request who is not the same that one of your action controller. It's why in this case i suggest you to use `getMasterRequest()` :). Maybe it's not your case, so my answer does not match your problem, but keep it somewhere, maybe it will be usefull later ;).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/include.html) included templates *should* have access to the variables of the active context. You can also add additional variables by passing them after the `with` keyword. Try passing the value like this:

```
{% set vars = {'route': app.request.attributes.get('_route')} %}
{% include 'shared/navbar.html.twig' with vars %}
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, I feel quite embarrassed but yet I provide the final answer. The function that fed the $menu array was a returning the template through $this->render instead of returning the array it should and thus all the confusion. Thanks to everyone for their input which allowed me to go through the code while trying different issues. Thanks